# SSRS Print in odd page

Tags: sql, printing, reporting-services, reporting

I'm trying to print a text box that is part of my footer on even pages only, so:

-I'm planning on using the text box properties - visibility(true,false)

-How do I use the PageNumber bult-in field to return the last digit of the PageNumber built-in field?

I'm plannig to set that digit equals to either (0-2-4-6-8), set the visibility property to true and hope that the text box will only show on those pages.

Let me know if this makes sense or have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a stretch, I'm not sure if this is possible but just to give you an idea on how it could be done you can add a global variable in the footer and put it in a textbox.

Then set the visibility to be dependent on the textbox value. For example

=IIF (footertextbox1.value = 2 Or 4 OR 6 Or 8, True,False)

Comment: other person in my team just helped me out:                       =iif(Globals!PageNumber Mod 2,True,False)     write this on the vibibility if the text box I wanted to show

Comment: I didn't know you could use Mod2 For for pages! Awesome, thanks for posting your answer.